# How to Appropriately Configure Server, XML, and JSP files in a Java web application?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

I am learning how to create dynamic web applications in Java. I am having some trouble **understanding how to connect the JSP files, XML files, and servlet** together.

Here are files from my current project, which results in a `404 resource not found error`.

1. **Servlet** - *Assumption*: the servlet file needs no reference to the jsp or xml because I am formatting using a web.xml instead of annotations.
2. **XML** - *Assumption A*: `welcome-file tag` must connect to "`fileName.jsp`". *Assumption B*: `url-pattern tag` must contain "`/nameOfJSPMinusFileExtension`"

   ```
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
3. **JSP** - *Assumption*: the `action` property in the `form` tag must contain "`/nameOfJSPFile`"

The aforementioned configuration yields the following:
[image: 404 resource not found error on the HTTP page]

Could anyone explain **the flow of these files and their annotations in terms of how they relate to one another** to form the dynamic web app? I and others might benefit from understanding the relationship between the three.

Comment: What documents or books have you read? If none, what tutorials have you accomplished? What exactly was there not clear? Then such question can be answered here.

Comment: @mentallurg Pardon if that is a broad question. I have instructors who help teach, but I was hoping for someone to explain the flow in how the web app loads based on its various files. Are there tutorials you recommend?

Comment: It is a matter personal preferences. Just google for *javaee servlets jsp tomcat tutorial*. You will see from very brief ones like this https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-servlet-quick-start-tomcat-xml-config or this https://www.baeldung.com/jsp to more solid ones like this https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html and this https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html (they are related to Java EE 5, but can be good to start).

Answer (score 0):

My configuration was correct. Here is what resolved my error: right click project directory in eclipse -> run server. (I had been trying to right click and run from only the servlet class).

If anyone still wants to elaborate on how xml/jsp/servers connect, feel free.